# DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging - Protocol error: This message has a timestamp of {0}, which is beyond the allowable clock skew for in the future

Tags: c#, asp.net, protocols, dotnetopenauth

I got a error from openid provider

> 2010-08-26 16:54:30,240 (GMT+4) [26] ERROR DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging - Protocol error: This message has a timestamp of 26.08.2010 16:54:37, which is beyond the allowable clock skew for in the future

What is the reason of such error?

Full log

```
2010-08-26 16:54:29,849 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Preparing to send CheckIdRequest (2.0) message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,849 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ExtensionsBindingElement applied to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,849 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySecurityOptions did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,849 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.BackwardCompatibilityBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,849 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToNonceBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,849 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToSignatureBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,849 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardReplayProtectionBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,849 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,849 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.SigningBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,849 (GMT+4) [26] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Prepared outgoing CheckIdRequest (2.0) message for http://openid.mail.ru/login: 
 openid.claimed_id: http://openid.mail.ru/mail/mishenkovks
 openid.identity: http://openid.mail.ru/mail/mishenkovks
 openid.assoc_handle: 7e519423f6aa520fc96f522f63016344
 openid.return_to: http://id.rc.afisha.ru/openidcallback.aspx?openidname=openid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&loginname=mishenkovks&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=openid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks
 openid.realm: http://id.rc.afisha.ru/
 openid.mode: checkid_setup
 openid.ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
 openid.ns.sreg: http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1
 openid.sreg.required: email,gender
 openid.sreg.optional: 

2010-08-26 16:54:29,849 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Sending message: CheckIdRequest
2010-08-26 16:54:29,849 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - Redirecting to http://openid.mail.ru/login?openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&openid.assoc_handle=7e519423f6aa520fc96f522f63016344&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fid.rc.afisha.ru%2Fopenidcallback.aspx%3Fopenidname%3Dopenid.mail.ru%252Fmail%252Fmishenkovks%26loginname%3Dmishenkovks%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dopenid.mail.ru%252Fmail%252Fmishenkovks&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Fid.rc.afisha.ru%2F&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1&openid.sreg.required=email%2Cgender&openid.sreg.optional=
2010-08-26 16:54:29,943 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Preparing to send AssociateDiffieHellmanRequest (2.0) message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,943 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ExtensionsBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,943 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySecurityOptions did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,943 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.BackwardCompatibilityBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,943 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToNonceBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,943 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToSignatureBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,943 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardReplayProtectionBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,943 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,943 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.SigningBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,943 (GMT+4) [26] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Prepared outgoing AssociateDiffieHellmanRequest (2.0) message for http://openid.mail.ru/login: 
 openid.dh_modulus: ANz5OguIOXLsDhmYmsWizjEOHTdxfo2Vcbt2I3MYZuYe91ouJ4mLBX+YkcLiemOcPym2CBRYHNOyyjmG0mg3BVd9RcLn5S3IHHoXGHblzqdLFEi/368Ygo79JRnxTkXjgmY0rxlJ5bU1zIKaSDuKdiI+XUkKJX8Fvf8W8vsixYOr
 openid.dh_gen: Ag==
 openid.dh_consumer_public: bT/gaYOqAG8mhwhdQQDvp0mOwBea3CPah26W+y1PjlbJMA/TJgg0Qlf07OA9XdLlgmE1rwE8PUkrT4dZSX/Wcz/zLK64DekxzMz/lI/YFNt5RZL+PQPNkxVQNh05niYUpnyRbawvj5MRtf+wvZY3IIqTwOXEk2hwmVo/CuXrjME=
 openid.assoc_type: HMAC-SHA256
 openid.session_type: DH-SHA256
 openid.mode: associate
 openid.ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0

2010-08-26 16:54:29,943 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Sending AssociateDiffieHellmanRequest request.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,943 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - HTTP POST http://openid.mail.ru/login
2010-08-26 16:54:29,943 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Received AssociateDiffieHellmanResponse response.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,943 (GMT+4) [26] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Processing incoming AssociateDiffieHellmanResponse (2.0) message:
 dh_server_public: AZmGkLLg0H8k96Uvi3dOgQV7cQ6GN2mcW24vTlCzYEP12CbHJ0cAwz/vqIoAUqArr55yMHTIOyWcXsPDPoalsk9nbs8nUmZQgTpB54SkwUfolHFy6nhkkL8oe8LkF2yN3/P/dhv80p+PUH5Fzh7vZqs8f0JD7IeBDh1J3cRY+8M=
 enc_mac_key: ARNtE1XPRpoUt+3+aDmKKlXIoqrHrzASCt+rWq6dgOQ=
 assoc_handle: 74e569c6b1bff96ff94ed9ecbec61c07
 assoc_type: HMAC-SHA256
 session_type: DH-SHA256
 expires_in: 60
 ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0

2010-08-26 16:54:29,959 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToSignatureBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,959 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.BackwardCompatibilityBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,959 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.SigningBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,959 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,959 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardReplayProtectionBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,959 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToNonceBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,959 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySecurityOptions did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,959 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ExtensionsBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,959 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - After binding element processing, the received AssociateDiffieHellmanResponse (2.0) message is: 
 dh_server_public: AZmGkLLg0H8k96Uvi3dOgQV7cQ6GN2mcW24vTlCzYEP12CbHJ0cAwz/vqIoAUqArr55yMHTIOyWcXsPDPoalsk9nbs8nUmZQgTpB54SkwUfolHFy6nhkkL8oe8LkF2yN3/P/dhv80p+PUH5Fzh7vZqs8f0JD7IeBDh1J3cRY+8M=
 enc_mac_key: ARNtE1XPRpoUt+3+aDmKKlXIoqrHrzASCt+rWq6dgOQ=
 assoc_handle: 74e569c6b1bff96ff94ed9ecbec61c07
 assoc_type: HMAC-SHA256
 session_type: DH-SHA256
 expires_in: 60
 ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0

2010-08-26 16:54:29,974 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Preparing to send CheckIdRequest (2.0) message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,974 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ExtensionsBindingElement applied to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,974 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySecurityOptions did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,974 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.BackwardCompatibilityBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,974 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToNonceBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,974 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToSignatureBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,974 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardReplayProtectionBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,974 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,974 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.SigningBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:29,974 (GMT+4) [26] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Prepared outgoing CheckIdRequest (2.0) message for http://openid.mail.ru/login: 
 openid.claimed_id: http://openid.mail.ru/mail/mishenkovks
 openid.identity: http://openid.mail.ru/mail/mishenkovks
 openid.assoc_handle: 74e569c6b1bff96ff94ed9ecbec61c07
 openid.return_to: http://id.rc.afisha.ru/openidcallback.aspx?openidname=openid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&loginname=mishenkovks&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=openid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks
 openid.realm: http://id.rc.afisha.ru/
 openid.mode: checkid_setup
 openid.ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
 openid.ns.sreg: http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1
 openid.sreg.required: email,gender
 openid.sreg.optional: 

2010-08-26 16:54:29,974 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Sending message: CheckIdRequest
2010-08-26 16:54:29,974 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - Redirecting to http://openid.mail.ru/login?openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&openid.assoc_handle=74e569c6b1bff96ff94ed9ecbec61c07&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fid.rc.afisha.ru%2Fopenidcallback.aspx%3Fopenidname%3Dopenid.mail.ru%252Fmail%252Fmishenkovks%26loginname%3Dmishenkovks%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dopenid.mail.ru%252Fmail%252Fmishenkovks&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Fid.rc.afisha.ru%2F&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1&openid.sreg.required=email%2Cgender&openid.sreg.optional=
2010-08-26 16:54:30,053 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Preparing to send AssociateDiffieHellmanRequest (2.0) message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,053 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ExtensionsBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,053 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySecurityOptions did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,053 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.BackwardCompatibilityBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,053 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToNonceBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,053 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToSignatureBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,053 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardReplayProtectionBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,053 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,053 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.SigningBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,053 (GMT+4) [26] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Prepared outgoing AssociateDiffieHellmanRequest (2.0) message for http://openid.mail.ru/login: 
 openid.dh_modulus: ANz5OguIOXLsDhmYmsWizjEOHTdxfo2Vcbt2I3MYZuYe91ouJ4mLBX+YkcLiemOcPym2CBRYHNOyyjmG0mg3BVd9RcLn5S3IHHoXGHblzqdLFEi/368Ygo79JRnxTkXjgmY0rxlJ5bU1zIKaSDuKdiI+XUkKJX8Fvf8W8vsixYOr
 openid.dh_gen: Ag==
 openid.dh_consumer_public: fkJbZBHaHiRYyx38Ls6KLW1s8pXge9rv7x0eMBtH+kb/eaqSGF1xpOczkO0/bkDyQiNEJz9/+FZvu7CJ8eF80p9veUJPhN1IRAzze2M82Dp7ljGkGOeFTVRPx9ieTA45lLItgYnxKNCEnUa3M3KABXH436lRuA/yo/9k6cjBpFQ=
 openid.assoc_type: HMAC-SHA256
 openid.session_type: DH-SHA256
 openid.mode: associate
 openid.ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0

2010-08-26 16:54:30,053 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Sending AssociateDiffieHellmanRequest request.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,068 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - HTTP POST http://openid.mail.ru/login
2010-08-26 16:54:30,068 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Received AssociateDiffieHellmanResponse response.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,068 (GMT+4) [26] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Processing incoming AssociateDiffieHellmanResponse (2.0) message:
 dh_server_public: AKZnKScjdbjDxR171/rT5jjhpVlbZ1llEbkzjadNJeGwrbYn2rbKtwUL3kFyY6ueTEhYtt5EHn7c4ZAw+7sCfu5pa1rmMnSaEaq4VqqfGED6RGBapUc3KI2Py0OPr516KjGu/jy3DzRXSVN1JQyfkYApOXromiTw9uQXKF8ZFBmW
 enc_mac_key: lZsvmB1zJmWdtA22MYyCyekRrR3NNQnYDR1o8xy5pZI=
 assoc_handle: 4ce9250fcad81195ace9cd9956134201
 assoc_type: HMAC-SHA256
 session_type: DH-SHA256
 expires_in: 60
 ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0

2010-08-26 16:54:30,068 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToSignatureBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,068 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.BackwardCompatibilityBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,068 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.SigningBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,068 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,068 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardReplayProtectionBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,068 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToNonceBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,068 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySecurityOptions did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,068 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ExtensionsBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,068 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - After binding element processing, the received AssociateDiffieHellmanResponse (2.0) message is: 
 dh_server_public: AKZnKScjdbjDxR171/rT5jjhpVlbZ1llEbkzjadNJeGwrbYn2rbKtwUL3kFyY6ueTEhYtt5EHn7c4ZAw+7sCfu5pa1rmMnSaEaq4VqqfGED6RGBapUc3KI2Py0OPr516KjGu/jy3DzRXSVN1JQyfkYApOXromiTw9uQXKF8ZFBmW
 enc_mac_key: lZsvmB1zJmWdtA22MYyCyekRrR3NNQnYDR1o8xy5pZI=
 assoc_handle: 4ce9250fcad81195ace9cd9956134201
 assoc_type: HMAC-SHA256
 session_type: DH-SHA256
 expires_in: 60
 ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0

2010-08-26 16:54:30,099 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Preparing to send CheckIdRequest (2.0) message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,099 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ExtensionsBindingElement applied to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,099 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySecurityOptions did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,099 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.BackwardCompatibilityBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,099 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToNonceBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,099 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToSignatureBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,099 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardReplayProtectionBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,099 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,099 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.SigningBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,099 (GMT+4) [26] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Prepared outgoing CheckIdRequest (2.0) message for http://openid.mail.ru/login: 
 openid.claimed_id: http://openid.mail.ru/mail/mishenkovks
 openid.identity: http://openid.mail.ru/mail/mishenkovks
 openid.assoc_handle: 4ce9250fcad81195ace9cd9956134201
 openid.return_to: http://id.rc.afisha.ru/openidcallback.aspx?openidname=openid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&loginname=mishenkovks&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=openid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks
 openid.realm: http://id.rc.afisha.ru/
 openid.mode: checkid_setup
 openid.ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
 openid.ns.sreg: http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1
 openid.sreg.required: email,gender
 openid.sreg.optional: 

2010-08-26 16:54:30,099 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Sending message: CheckIdRequest
2010-08-26 16:54:30,099 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - Redirecting to http://openid.mail.ru/login?openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&openid.assoc_handle=4ce9250fcad81195ace9cd9956134201&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fid.rc.afisha.ru%2Fopenidcallback.aspx%3Fopenidname%3Dopenid.mail.ru%252Fmail%252Fmishenkovks%26loginname%3Dmishenkovks%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dopenid.mail.ru%252Fmail%252Fmishenkovks&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Fid.rc.afisha.ru%2F&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1&openid.sreg.required=email%2Cgender&openid.sreg.optional=
2010-08-26 16:54:30,240 (GMT+4) [26] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Scanning incoming request for messages: http://id.rc.afisha.ru/openidcallback.aspx?openidname=openid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&loginname=mishenkovks&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=openid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.mail.ru%2Flogin&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fid.rc.afisha.ru%2Fopenidcallback.aspx%3Fopenidname%3Dopenid.mail.ru%252Fmail%252Fmishenkovks%26loginname%3Dmishenkovks%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dopenid.mail.ru%252Fmail%252Fmishenkovks&openid.response_nonce=2010-08-26T16%3A54%3A37ZMKABBO&openid.assoc_handle=4ce9250fcad81195ace9cd9956134201&openid.sreg.email=mishenkovks%40mail.ru&openid.sreg.gender=M&openid.signed=ns%2Cmode%2Cop_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle%2Csreg.email%2Csreg.gender&openid.sig=cZDadOjjURwbrL2tbWDWcaqXTFMuXs8b0OdX2hwQurQ%3D
2010-08-26 16:54:30,240 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Incoming HTTP request: GET http://id.rc.afisha.ru/openidcallback.aspx?openidname=openid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&loginname=mishenkovks&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=openid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.mail.ru%2Flogin&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fid.rc.afisha.ru%2Fopenidcallback.aspx%3Fopenidname%3Dopenid.mail.ru%252Fmail%252Fmishenkovks%26loginname%3Dmishenkovks%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dopenid.mail.ru%252Fmail%252Fmishenkovks&openid.response_nonce=2010-08-26T16%3A54%3A37ZMKABBO&openid.assoc_handle=4ce9250fcad81195ace9cd9956134201&openid.sreg.email=mishenkovks%40mail.ru&openid.sreg.gender=M&openid.signed=ns%2Cmode%2Cop_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle%2Csreg.email%2Csreg.gender&openid.sig=cZDadOjjURwbrL2tbWDWcaqXTFMuXs8b0OdX2hwQurQ%3D
2010-08-26 16:54:30,240 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Incoming request received: PositiveAssertionResponse
2010-08-26 16:54:30,240 (GMT+4) [26] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Processing incoming PositiveAssertionResponse (2.0) message:
 openid.claimed_id: http://openid.mail.ru/mail/mishenkovks
 openid.identity: http://openid.mail.ru/mail/mishenkovks
 openid.sig: cZDadOjjURwbrL2tbWDWcaqXTFMuXs8b0OdX2hwQurQ=
 openid.signed: ns,mode,op_endpoint,claimed_id,identity,return_to,response_nonce,assoc_handle,sreg.email,sreg.gender
 openid.assoc_handle: 4ce9250fcad81195ace9cd9956134201
 openid.op_endpoint: http://openid.mail.ru/login
 openid.return_to: http://id.rc.afisha.ru/openidcallback.aspx?openidname=openid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&loginname=mishenkovks&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=openid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks
 openid.response_nonce: 2010-08-26T16:54:37ZMKABBO
 openid.mode: id_res
 openid.ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
 openidname: openid.mail.ru/mail/mishenkovks
 loginname: mishenkovks
 dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier: openid.mail.ru/mail/mishenkovks
 openid.sreg.email: mishenkovks@mail.ru
 openid.sreg.gender: M

2010-08-26 16:54:30,240 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToSignatureBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,240 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.BackwardCompatibilityBindingElement did not apply to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,240 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Verifying incoming PositiveAssertionResponse message signature of: cZDadOjjURwbrL2tbWDWcaqXTFMuXs8b0OdX2hwQurQ=
2010-08-26 16:54:30,240 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.Signatures - Signing these message parts: 
 ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
 mode: id_res
 op_endpoint: http://openid.mail.ru/login
 claimed_id: http://openid.mail.ru/mail/mishenkovks
 identity: http://openid.mail.ru/mail/mishenkovks
 return_to: http://id.rc.afisha.ru/openidcallback.aspx?openidname=openid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks&loginname=mishenkovks&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=openid.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmishenkovks
 response_nonce: 2010-08-26T16:54:37ZMKABBO
 assoc_handle: 4ce9250fcad81195ace9cd9956134201
 sreg.email: mishenkovks@mail.ru
 sreg.gender: M

Base64 representation of signed data: 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
Signature: cZDadOjjURwbrL2tbWDWcaqXTFMuXs8b0OdX2hwQurQ=
2010-08-26 16:54:30,240 (GMT+4) [26] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.SigningBindingElement applied to message.
2010-08-26 16:54:30,240 (GMT+4) [26] ERROR DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging - Protocol error: This message has a timestamp of 26.08.2010 16:54:37, which is beyond the allowable clock skew for in the future.
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ErrorUtilities.VerifyProtocol(Boolean condition, String message, Object[] args)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement.ProcessIncomingMessage(IProtocolMessage message)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.ProcessIncomingMessage(IProtocolMessage message)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.OpenIdChannel.ProcessIncomingMessage(IProtocolMessage message)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.ReadFromRequest(HttpRequestInfo httpRequest)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.GetResponse(HttpRequestInfo httpRequestInfo)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.GetResponse()
   at Afisha.ID.openidcallback.LoginByOpenId()
   at Afisha.ID.openidcallback.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at Afisha.ID.Classes.ObjectPageBaseClasses.FrameActionPageBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.openidcallback_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your log file uses timestamps in local time, but the log *message* expresses the message timestamp in UTC time.  So although they look like the timestamps are reasonably close, they are actually four hours off.  *One* of the servers has the wrong time or timezone set.

Comment: thanks, i am agre with you!
our admin trying to setup time synchronize service, but without any success :(

Comment: Thanks, this helped me fix this exact same issue. Turns out the time on my system clock was right, but the time zone was set to UTC time. Over two hours of debugging a production machine only to find out it was the clock...grr.