# Protocol Error: Messaging Signature was incorrect

Tags: dotnetopenauth

We are implementing our own OAuth2 based Authorization Server as well as Resource Server. I followed the sample provided for Resource Server and Authorization Server.

Authorization Server seems to be working fine...I am able to generate access token and store it in my own db.

However, I am not able to suceed with Resource Server.

I am using the same Public and Private key used while authorizing....

I always get, below messae ... I am using standard WPF Test Client provided in sample to test my server. Please help guys.

```
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging: 2013-12-18 15:11:31,005 (GMT+5) [32] ERROR DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging - Protocol error: Message signature was incorrect.
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ErrorUtilities.VerifyProtocol(Boolean condition, String unformattedMessage, Object[] args)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.DataBagFormatterBase`1.Deserialize(T message, String value, IProtocolMessage containingMessage, String messagePartName)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.StandardAccessTokenAnalyzer.DeserializeAccessToken(IDirectedProtocolMessage message, String accessToken)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ResourceServer.GetAccessToken(HttpRequestBase httpRequestInfo, String[] requiredScopes)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ResourceServer.GetPrincipal(HttpRequestBase httpRequestInfo, String[] requiredScopes)
   at Decos.OAuth.ServiceProvider.Library.Server.OAuth2ResourceServerHost.GetPrincipal(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at Decos.OAuth.ServiceProvider.Filters.ValidateOAuth2Request.VerifyRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at Decos.OAuth.ServiceProvider.Filters.ValidateOAuth2Request.AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

Comment: Check this out, may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575864/dotnetopenauth-messaging-protocol-error-this-message-has-a-timestamp-of-0

Comment: I looked at that post ...but as of now, My server and Client are same machine ... so, would that still be an issue ?

Comment: I am not sure about this but I had a similar problem long ago and I was able to solve it by updating my system time from the internet. I don't know how it worked. But "it worked" :)